Dynamically set SpringBoot CronJob Scheduler interval
I plan to use Spring Boot's @Scheduler annotation to run cron jobs for various tasks. Currently, the job simply prints 'Hello' every minute. I have a table detailing the cron jobs, with one column reserved for the cron expression, e.g., 0 * * * * *. This expression is retrieved from the table and used to schedule the cron job. My intention is to enable interval updates via the database rather than through code changes.
The current implementation works, but the job only runs once and fails to run again. I have checked with breakpoints and noted the log time at which the job first ran but without luck it did not run again
private void getCronDetails() {
   //Returns map of <cronjobName, cronSchedule> e.g. <myJobName, "0 * * * * *">
    List<Map<String, String>> schedulesFromDBList = cronJobRepository.getCronJobSchedule();
    for (Map<String, String> scheduleMap : schedulesFromDBList) {
        String cronJobName = scheduleMap.get(JobName);
        String cronSchedule = scheduleMap.get(CronSchedule);
        cronJobSchedules.put(cronJobName, cronSchedule);
    }
}

@Scheduled(cron = "#{@cronJobSchedules.get('MyJobName')}", zone = TIME_ZONE, initialDelayString = "#{@initialDelay}")
public void accountCleanupJob() {
      System.out.println("hello");
}

Map contains the job name and the cron schedule. Extra logic is done using the job name but that isn't required. This job runs once only and fails to begin unless I have 'initialDelayString'
Should I change to a fixed expression rather than retrieving from the DB?

I have approached this requirement before not using the @Scheduled annotation but like this:

Define a Service or Configuration class that is responsible for managing the scheduling. Have this class implement the Spring interface org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer
Implement the Functional interface: void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar)
Read your schedules from the database and register new Cron Tasks providing a callback to the your execution code

Something like this:
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.CronTask;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
public class ScheduleManager implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        // read from DB...
        List<Map<String, String>> schedulesFromDBList = cronJobRepository.getCronJobSchedule();
        for (Map<String, String> scheduleMap : schedulesFromDBList) {
            String cronJobName = scheduleMap.get(JobName);
            String cronSchedule = scheduleMap.get(CronSchedule);

            taskRegistrar.addCronTask(
                    new CronTask(this::myTask, cronSchedule)
            );

        }
    }

    private void myTask() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}

Some adaption required if you need to dynamically respond to changed task schedules.

Thanks a lot for this response. I’ll try it out. Ill  have another task to continually update the map too in case of a change to the table data
